# Do hidden items get published?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am looking to find out whether or not Items that are either descendants of or are, themselves, hidden items get published when a user Publishes or Republishes the content tree.

I know that this is a pretty basic question, but I haven't been able to find the answer online, and I do not currently have an instance set up with additional roles and users, to use  to test this.

Thanks for your help! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Items which have `Hidden` field set to true are published as any other items.

Still remember that this is up to you what kind of access rights you'll set for them and who will be able to access them.

Comment: So if I set an item to be hidden from a user/role but don't remove publishing rights, it will still publish. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it will still publish. Reading this I think you're either removing inheritance or denying read rights - is that correct? If so, you might want to take a look at Configure -> Hide Item (In the Attributes chunk). That will hide it for everyone, until they say that they want to view hidden items (ticking the tickbox in the View tab)

Comment: If you need to prevent users from publishing items they do not have access to then you need to set `Publishing.CheckSecurity` and `Publishing.RequireTargetDeleteRightWhenCheckingSecurity` http://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/publishing-security-basics/

Answer (score 5):

By hidden items - do you mean things like the /sitecore/System folder? In any case, as long as it's publishable (i.e. not in workflow, not set as unpublishable in publishing restrictions and the like), it will be published.

**Edit** 
It is important to note that it's parent/ancestors should also be publishable, otherwise it'll still not be published.

Comment: I posted a clarification question on Maras' post, but was really for both of you :)

Comment: Seems like neither @Trayek nor I guessed what "hidden items" meant in this context ;)

Answer (score 1):

All items get published unless marked as Never Publish or have Publish End Date set to earlier than today (In this case the already published items get unpublished/deleted from web database)